# How to print the command line output in a text area line by line using java?

Tags: java, swing, cmd, runtime, jtextarea

I have a code that runs a command but it's output didn't get in the text area simultaneously. 
It displays the output after all process has done. 
So I need the output line by line printed in the text area.

Here is my code:

```
try{
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null,dir);

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command

            while ((k = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                 //result= result +"\n"+k+"\n";
                 edlflashTextArea.append(k);
                 System.out.println(k);
            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command

            while ((k = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                //result= result+"\n"+k+"\n";
                edlflashTextArea.append(k);
            }
            edlflashTextArea.append("DONE");


} catch (IOException l) {
            System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
            StringWriter sw= new StringWriter();
            l.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String ExceptionAsString=sw.toString();
            System.out.println(ExceptionAsString);
            edlflashTextArea.append(ExceptionAsString);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append a new line (`"\n"`) character at the end of the line:

```
edlflashTextArea.append("\n");
```